# The meaning of "Record" in Graduate Record Examinations

Tags: meaning

I understand that the Graduate **Record** Examinations (GRE) is an admissions requirement for graduate schools in the United States.

What does "record" mean here? Why is it not Graduate **Admissions** Examinations?

Comment: Perhaps to distinguish it from many other admission tests and examinations set by individual graduate schools.

Comment: The truth is, I don't really know, and I can't seem to easily find any information on the original reasoning.  The test was originally adopted only among a handful of Ivy League schools, and the administrators of the test possibly thought it a good way to **record** the status of certain graduates as ready for more advanced work.  I'm sure it made sense at the time -- but now it's just what the test is called.

Comment: Neither Wikipedia, the Kaplan site, nor the Educational Testing Site appear to address the question. As @Andrew notes, we don't seem to have any information available from when it was initially designed.